# Does Skeptics.SE presuppose methodological naturalism?

Tags: discussion, skepticism

Does Skeptics.SE presuppose methodological naturalism—i.e., the claim that everything can be explained by natural processes or that there is no such thing as miracles?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the [tour for Skeptics.SE](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/tour) our scope is defined:

> Skeptics is a question and answer site for **applying scientific skepticism**

In the [Welcome to New Users](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/faq-welcome-to-new-users) FAQ question, provides a link to a definition on Wikipedia:

> This site is about applying [scientific skepticism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_skepticism). We only accept answers based on independently verifiable applications of the scientific method ("facts").

Wikipedia's overview currently says:

> Scientific skeptics attempt to evaluate claims based on verifiability and falsifiability; they discourage accepting claims which rely on faith or anecdotal evidence.

Now whether scientific skepticism presupposes [methodological naturalism](https://rationalwiki.org/wiki/Methodological_naturalism) is probably a great question for Philosophy.SE. I have to admit, I haven't much patience with such matters, and I am happy to leave it to others to work out.

When it comes to actual practice on this site, these topics have been thrashed out before:

- [Are religious questions on-topic?](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63/are-religious-questions-on-topic/)
- [Are religious miracle questions on-topic?](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3168/are-religious-miracle-questions-on-topic/)